# Why am I getting a key value coding compliance error?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, key-value-coding

At runtime my app is throwing this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x84231f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key count1.

The count1 in question is a label property.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *count1;
```

I link to it in the .xib file, I have commented out every single use of the property except for the declaration but the error persists. If I remove the property altogether I get the same exception problem but the key is now 'view' instead of count1.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not understanding your question, you have a label in your xib file referencing a property called `count1` and do you rename this property to `view` in your code and now do you get this error, am I wright?

Comment: You may have to link the `view` from the `file's owner` to the xib.

Comment: read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612426/error-terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsunknownkeyexception-reason

Answer (score 1):

The property is being accessed on `UIApplication`. Wherever you declared `count1`, it was not on `UIApplication`. It might have been a custom subclass of `UIApplication`, but you can't have changed `UIApplication` itself.

So, either something is attempting to access the `count1` property on the application object when you meant it to access it on some other object, or you meant to use a custom application object but you're not actually doing so. If you intend to use a custom subclass of `UIApplication` for your application object, be sure to pass that class's name to `UIApplicationMain()`. Otherwise, you have probably connected an outlet incorrectly.