# Cordova 3.8.0 Build Causes Errors in Iphone Apps locking up at Splash Screen

Tags: iphone, cordova, 64-bit, nsunknownkeyexception

I have downlaoded cordova 3.8 in order for the iphone app development to be 64 bit compliant for itunes

when i run the default app on my iphone the app builds fine in xcode however it crashes at the splash screen on my phone

the error message is as per below, please advise which files within the cordova structure i need to modify to remedy this

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2a46e49f 0x37c24c8b 0x2a46e1a9 0x2b0d4f59 0x2b0e71af 0x2a3be81d 0x2dcee421 0x2dcefd2d 0x2db934eb 0x2db92889 0x2db9d209 0x2db91217 0x30bff0d1 0x2a434d7d 0x2a434041 0x2a432b7b 0x2a3803c1 0x2a3801d3 0x2d9951bf 0x2d98ffa1 0x1076f3 0x381a4aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Hi can someone please advise where i can get help with my above question as to my surprise i am yet to receive any replies from the cordova community without which i cannot resolve the issue

Comment: Hi all 

In  the interest of giving back to the developer community i thought you may like to know i found a solution to the above post which is explained in the following solution provided by one of the others

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19093751/3205566